# How to change the version of python from 3.8 to 2.7

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, python-2.7, default

I need to use Python 2.7 in order to use PneumoCaT as it only runs with Python 2.7 not higher versions. I am trying to set my Python version from 3.8 to 2.7 in Ubuntu, but I can't do it.

This is the code I am using.

1. `ls /bin/python*`

   I have `/bin/python2.7` and `/bin/python3.8`

2. `python --version` comes up with Python 3.8.
3. `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

   I can choose from python 2 and 3. I chose python2.
4. Results of `python --version` still comes up with Python 3.8.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but on many on-topic OSes `python` maps to 2.7 by default; but as you've not provided specifics as to what you're running; how can we really help?  Guessing can lead to worse problems...

Comment: You should set up a python environment or use a VM. Changing the installed version of python can break your system. Will almost certainly break your system downgrading from 3.8 > 2.7

Comment: `Don't`. Use `python2 /path/to/program.py` instead. Alternatively, use a virtual environment (use your favorite search engine to know how to set it up), which will not mess up with the system's default python version.

Answer (score 5):

*python-is-python2* is a convenience package which ships a symlink to point `/usr/bin/python` interpreter at the current default python2. It may improve compatibility with obsolete third-party software, while breaking some modern software.

The current default Python 3 version in Ubuntu 20.04 is Python 3.8.10. To install python-is-python2 in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-is-python2
```

Comment: That package doesn't exist anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66129356/470749

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the tip. My answer has been updated.